# A: "I saw a girl" / "I saw it"; B: "was she beautiful?" or "is she beautiful?" / "was it nice?" or "is it nice?"

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

See this conversation

> A: I saw a girl
>
> B: was she beautiful? (or is she beautiful?)
>
> A: My mom gave me a pen.
>
> B: was it nice? (or is it nice?)

So, **which responses are ok or idiomatic?**

Comment: Both past and present are idiomatic **depending on what you mean**.

Comment: Was it nice? Sounds a bit like he's asking whether it was nice of her to give it you? But that's absolutely not the case.

Comment: English is not devoid of common sense. The sighting of the girl was fleeting; it happened once in the past ("saw"). We would not ask *What color hair **does** she have?* unless we see the speaker is in a reverie. The pen is a gift and you have probably not thrown it in the trash. We presume you still have it, absent information to the contrary, and so we would not ask ***Did** it write smoothly?* unless we thought this was a pen you no longer have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your responses are correct and idiomatic, but they would have different understandings.

Just because the initial statement is past tense, the follow up question say be either in the past or present tense depending on the context.

> I saw a girl *yesterday*.
>   *Is* she beautiful?
>   *Was* she beautiful?

are both correct, *is* is possible since on would not think her looks have changed much over the course of a day.  However,

> I remember I saw a girl ten years ago.
>
> *Is* she beautiful?

may not be appropriate since many things can change over ten years

> *Was* she beautiful.

would still be correct.

Comment: So, "**was**" is the safest way to say it, right?

Comment: @Tom Take that example of yours: My mom gave me a pen. **Was it nice?** - did something to happen to it since the time she gave you. How much time passed since then? **Is it nice?** - you still have it? Do you like it?